# jQuery how to select all tr elements from one row and up to a stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

A little odd situation. I'm writing a greasemonkey script on some legacy HTML where everything is put into one table. I want to select all TR elements from the one I click and the next 3-4-5-6 rows up to the next row that contains a TD.class_name

```
table
  ...
  tr -> td.class_name
  tr
  tr
  tr
  tr -> td.class_name
  ...
/table
```

So, in the above example I want to select rows 2,3,4 (and hide them, which is the trivial part). The challenge is that I don't know how many rows there are, and this table could be very long.

How could I do that in an elegant way in jQuery?

Comment: Do you have an example of the table in HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you understand the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    var fnc = function(){
        $(this).nextAll().each(function() {
            if (($(this)[0]) && ($(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase()=="tr")) {

                var td_lst = $(this).find('td[class="stop"]');
                if ($(td_lst).length!=0)
                    return false;

                $(this).css("background-color","#00FF66");

            } else {
                return false;
            }
    });
  }

  $('table tr[class="xevent"]').bind("click",   fnc);

}); 
</script>
<style>
    .stop{
        background-color:#009999;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr class="xevent"><td>text a</td><td class="stop">text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr class="xevent"><td>text a</td><td class="stop">text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr class="xevent"><td>text a</td><td class="stop">text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr class="xevent"><td>text a</td><td class="stop">text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text a</td><td>text b</td><td>text c</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing I learned is that .next() does not return hidden TR elements. Your example works because it traverses through .nextAll()

Comment: My first example was using .next() with a "while (true)". It worked but I did not think performer. then I switch to .nextAll() to improve

Answer (score 0):

```
var in_selection = false;
$('table#id tr').each(function () {
    if ($('td.class_name', this)) {
        if (in_selection) return false;
        in_selection = true;
    }
    if (in_selection) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    return true;
});
not tested
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I wasn't sure if you wanted to include the last row (highest up) with the `.class_name`, so I made an demo of the script on [this pastebin site](http://pastebin.me/c8c55500f38689083302845eca35cce5) and highlighted the rows it finds. You can remove the commented marks when you want it to actually remove the rows.

Here is the basic code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.class_name').click(function(){
  var row = $(this)[0].rowIndex - 1;
  $(this).addClass('removeme');
  for (j=0;j<row+1;j++){
   var el = $('table tr:eq('+(row-j)+')'); 
   if (el.hasClass('class_name')) {
    // el.addClass('removeme'); // Remove comment marks if you want this row included
    break;
   }
  el.addClass('removeme');
  }
 // $('.removeme').remove();  // Remove comment marks when you want to remove the rows
 });
});
```

If you did want to include the last (highest up) row with the `.class_name` class, then just un-comment out the `el.addClass('removeme');` before the `break`